# Do I have to repent to Allah before or after seeking forgiveness from someone for backbiting/ listening and do I have to pray Salat-Al-Tawbah?

Tags: salat, forgiveness, backbiting

Asalamualaikum, can I ask forgiveness from a person for backbiting/ listening to backbiting and then repent to Allah? Will I have to pray Salat-Al-Tawbah?